# How to track user journeys cross-domain only if the user enters domain B via domain A in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-analytics-4

I am trying to track traffic across two separate domains in GA4, one is owned by the company I work for (domainA), the other is owned by one of our partners (domainB). We have a need to track traffic coming from domainA to domainB and any events that occur when the users are on domainB, but we don't want to track users that didn't start their session at domainA. Essentially, unless domainA has referred the user to domainB, we don't want to track it.

I have set up data streams for domainA and domainB, and GA4 is collecting data between the two domains, however if a user starts their journey at domainB without ever having visited domainA, GA4 is still collecting that data and displaying it in the stats - we don't want this to happen.

The data stream for domainB has been configured to include domainA in the configure domain settings under Data Streams.

**✅ What we want**
[image: Diagram explaining flow that we want]

Any ideas on how this could be achieved? Is data streams using the correct method? Ideally, I would like minimal setup for domainB, if possible (for example, just one snippet in `<head>` to enable tracking).

Answer (score 0):

Well if you just want a snippet in head, you can rewrite your existing GA4 snippet to load the library conditionally. Given that you're not using GTM, that your domains are different TLDs and that you have the cross-domain linking between the A and B enabled, you could just check on page load whether the url contains the ?_ga parameter with your measurement id OR whether the special cookie flag is set. And if it is true, then re-create the special cookie flag and load the library as normal. If it's false, then don't do anything.

Alternatively, you could use the document.referrer for the same logic if your cross-domain is not needed due to the domains being not TLDs.

Comment: This would only work if the journey on domainB is contained to a single page, otherwise if a user visited multiple pages on domainB, GA4 would only collect data for the first page.
I'm having a really hard time finding clear instructions on how to implement tracking in this scenario. I can only find information on setting up cross-domain tracking when you own both websites, which collects all data from all domains with separate data streams

Comment: Nope. It will work for the whole domain B journey. Why do you think I'm setting the cookie flag? But you're having a hard time finding the info because your solution is not an industry standard. An industry standard is to have a pixel-based solution to track affiliate traffic conversions. You don't typically impose into a third party site with your whole analytics script and it's a miracle the client allows you to. I would definitely never allow something like this. Rarely, affiliates share GTM access, allowing for fine-tuning. That would also work better than a GA script.

Comment: This is why I asked if data streams were the correct method. This isn't a client, but a partner, we're working together, hence the "miracle". The ultimate goal we have is to track sign ups we've directed to their website, so in a nutshell our top priority is collecting form_submit events and being able to include this data in our stats within GA4 will give us insight into the effectiveness of our user funnels/journeys through to conversion (form_submit). If you can think of a better solution that is industry standard I'm more than happy to listen

Comment: Yeah, first you would shift all your tracking logic from imposing into the partner's DOM to their GTM if they use it. If they don't, then you're back in square one and my answer solves that. But even when you get into their GTM, you would reimplement the logic I described, but now with GTM's tools. Doing things through GTM just makes them a lot more visible and easier to maintain.